# How to calculate a Frobenius norm?

Tags: analysis, matrices

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times m$ ($n$ less than $m$) full rank matrix. Apply Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to the rows of $A$, then we get an $n \times m$ matrix $B$ with orthonormal columns. According to the Gram-Schmidt algorithm, there exists a lower triangular matrix $L_m$, such that $L_m A=B$.

Let $C=AA^*$, if the Frobenius norm of $C-I_n$,  $\|C-I_n\|=a$, can we calculate the Frobenius norm of $L_m C^{1/2}-I_n, \|L_m C^{1/2}-I_n\|$, where $C^{1/2}$ is the square root of $C$, and $I_n$ is the $n$ order identity matrix?

At least, can we prove that $\|L_m C^{1/2}-I_n\|$ is smaller that $\|C-I_n\|$?

Comment: Are you sure that it is the columns of $B$ which are orthonormal ($n<m$)? I would bet rather for rows.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Try running this in Matlab (or Octave).

```
iter=1;
n=3;
m=4;
while true
    A=randn(n,m);
    [Q R]=qr(A',0);
    L=inv(R)'; % B in question is Q'
    C=A*A';
    stuff=[norm(C-eye(n),'fro'), norm(L*C^(1/2)-eye(n),'fro')];
    if stuff(2) > stuff(1)
        fprintf('Found a counter-example at step %d!\n', iter); 
        break; 
    end; 
    iter=iter+1; 
end
```